# react.js event listener on none react elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering, what's the best practice to add an event listener to a DOM element, which is NOT rendered by react (a radio button)
I have a given html form and I want to use the advantages of react.js instead of playing around with jQuery ajax stuff.

With jQuery I would do something like that:

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=bedStatus]').change(function() {....}
```

Should I use something like this with react ()

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

Could someone push me in the right direction?

Cheers Kai

Answer (score 0):

For react elements created by your component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="radio" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In terms of best practices, usually the non-react element should be a `window` or `document`. If it is a HTML element, then probably it should be wrapped in a react component and the event listener should be as above.

For non-react elements your approach is very good. It is **very important to remove the listener when the component is unmounted**.

Listeners are usually attached after the component is mounted:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

**Important**: Remove when unmounted:

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

I repeat that this is usually done to attach events on `window` or `document` objects.

Depending on your use case it can be acceptable to attach to HTML elements of parent or child elements or even of some elements created dynamically. `findDOMNode()` can be useful in some cases. But it is advised to avoid doing this whenever possible.